# how to run javascript code in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I had a java script code in asp.net ,It's works fine in all browser but when javascript is disabled in browser the script is not working ,so can anyone suggest me where to write the code

Answer (score 1):

> so can anyone suggest me where to write the code

You don't have much choices left other than doing it on the server. Of course there are some levels of interaction that are possible only to be made with javascript. For example things like AJAX calls, subscription to events in DOM elements like `onchange`, ... If the user disables javascript your site will become less dynamic, that's for sure.

If you absolutely need to use javascript you could tell the user that your site requires it in order to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there is no way around it...if javascript is disabled...then give users a message to turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

You could alert the user using the noscript-tag that he or she should turn it javascript back on

```
    <noscript>
       Javascript is disabled
    </noscript>
```